# Where is the "About Gnome" dialog in gnome-shell?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm used to Gnome 2 in Debian and Fedora.  But recently I've been using Gnome 3 and Gnome-shell (3.0.2).  Today I noticed I wasn't able to find the About Gnome dialog.  It's been helpful in the past to pull it up to see what version of Gnome I'm running, and see some attribution information.
So, questions:

1. Where does the About Gnome dialog live in Gnome 3 / Gnome-shell?
2. If it has been removed, was this a Gnome decision, or my distro (fedora)?
3. Are there relevant software license requirements about attribution that is user-facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *System settings > System > System info* (or *Details* on some distros). On all distros, in terminal:

   ```
   gnome-control-center info
   ```
2. As far as I understand from Gnome's IRC channel, it is an upstream decision.

Comment: It's funny that on my Fedora box, there is no "System" entry under "System Settings". However if you type "System Info" into the application search box it will appear :)